# how to merge non-null data rows into one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to merge data rows for example:

```
pid   seq   str1    str2    str3
1     1     NULL    mary    NULL
1     2     jim     craig   NULL
1     3     kevin   NULL    NULL
2     1    david    NULL    NULL
2     2    NULL     annie   NULL
```

Should become:

```
pid str1    str2    str3
1   kevin   craig   NULL
2   david   annie   NULL
```

The following works, but very slow, because the table involved has about 1/2 millions rows and there are 30 columns to operate.

```
select pid,                             
(select top 1 p1.str1 from mytable p1 where p1.pid=p2.pid and p1.str1 is not null order by seq desc),
(select top 1 p1.str2 from mytable p1 where p1.pid=p2.pid and p1.str2 is not null order by seq desc),
(select top 1 p1.str3 from mytable p1 where p1.pid=p2.pid and p1.str3 is not null order by seq desc),
...
from mytable p2
group by pid
```

I have seen articles online suggesting using FOR XML PATH(). But since that also involves select queries like what I have above, I don't think it'd perform much better. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
create table temp(
    pid int,
    seq int,
    str1 varchar(50),
    str2 varchar(50),
    str3 varchar(50)
)
insert into temp
select 1, 1, NULL, 'mary', NULL union all 
select 1, 2, 'jim', 'craig', NULL union all 
select 1, 3, 'kevin', NULL, NULL union all 
select 2, 1, 'david', NULL, NULL union all 
select 2, 2, NULL, 'annie', NULL


;with cte as(
    select 
        *,
        rn1 = row_number() over (partition by pid order by case when str1 is not null then seq else 0 end desc),
        rn2 = row_number() over (partition by pid order by case when str2 is not null then seq else 0 end desc),
        rn3 = row_number() over (partition by pid order by case when str3 is not null then seq else 0 end desc)
    from temp
)
select
    pid,
    str1 = max(case when rn1 = 1 then str1 end),
    str2 = max(case when rn2 = 1 then str2 end),
    str3 = max(case when rn3 = 1 then str3 end)
from cte
group by pid

drop table temp
```